# Android 4.x: detect mouse or touchscreen mode

Tags: android, mouse, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, touchscreen, android-4.2-jelly-bean

There is an API to detect if Android 4.x (ICS or JB) is in touchscreen or mouse mode. Android can actually go from one mode to the other: if you are in mouse mode (a cursor is displayed) and you do a touchscreen press, the mouse will disappear. In an apk application, I would like to query the state of mouse vs. touchscreen. This feature is only for > 4.0. Does anyone know this API?

Comment: have you tried isintouchmode http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInTouchMode%28%29?

Comment: Is there similar functionality to detect this in Javascript on a web page? To set a hover event for mouse, and click/tap event for other Androids, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by nandeesh in the comment section, "isintouchmode" is the answer to this question.